# Connecting to gmail/facebook accounts through android webview iframe causing crash

Tags: android, iframe, webview, java-native-interface, chromium

As I am trying to connect to Facebook through an iframe on my android app. A crash occurs when I try to type the username and password. Specifically when I try to type either the username or password the first time I am able to enter data fine, but when I switch from the username field to the password field or vice-versa I am experiencing a crash.

This crash is only specific to android lolipop

The crash logs only say this :

```
12-17 14:52:04.242  A/chromium﹕ [FATAL:jni_android.cc(271)] Check failed: false. 
12-17 14:52:04.243  A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT),code -6 in tid 28156
```

My code that sets up the android webview iframe for the facebook/gmail connect is :

```
public static void show(Activity mainActivity, Context mainContext, WebViewClient client, IframeAgentInterface javascriptInterface, String javascriptInterfacename,String url,int width, int height)
{   
        boolean isLocalFile = false;

        Point screenSize = new Point();
        if(width == -1 || height == -1) {
            mainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(screenSize);
        }

        if(width == -1){
            width = screenSize.x - 150;
        }
        if(height == -1){
            height = screenSize.y - 150;
        }

        MobileIframeWebView.width = width;
        MobileIframeWebView.height = height;
        MobileIframeWebView.activity = mainActivity;

        MobileIframeWebView.context = mainContext;
        MobileIframeWebView.parentView = (AppFwkWebView)(MobileIframeWebView.activity.findViewById(R.id.sasappview));
        MobileIframeWebView.client = client;

        if (url.startsWith(PREFIX_WEB_URL_HTTP))
            MobileIframeWebView.url = url;
        else {

            isLocalFile = true;
            MobileIframeWebView.url = FileHelper.GetLocalFileURL(url);

            // check if file exists
            if (!FileHelper.DoesFileExist(url))
                return;

            // now check if the file needs to be opened in a browser, that is
            // if the webview cannot open it
            if (FileHelper.IsWebViewFileType(MobileIframeWebView.url)) {

                startBrowserActivity(mainActivity, mainContext, MobileIframeWebView.url);
                return;
            }
        }

        MobileIframeWebView.javascriptInterface = javascriptInterface;
        MobileIframeWebView.javascriptInterfaceName = javascriptInterfacename;
        mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                LayoutInflater inflater =LayoutInflater.from(MobileIframeWebView.context);
                LinearLayout iframeLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.iframe_skeleton, null,false);

                iframeLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MobileIframeWebView.width,MobileIframeWebView.height));

                MobileIframeWebView.popup = new PopupWindow(
                        iframeLayout,
                        MobileIframeWebView.width,
                        MobileIframeWebView.height,
                        true);

                //show the iframe
                MobileIframeWebView.openedIframe = (MobileIframeWebView) (iframeLayout.findViewById(R.id.view_iframe));
                View emptySpace = (View) (iframeLayout.findViewById(R.id.empty_space_close_iframe));
                ImageView closewv = (ImageView) (iframeLayout.findViewById(R.id.close_iframe));

                int emptySpaceWidth = MobileIframeWebView.width - closewv.getLayoutParams().width;
                if(emptySpaceWidth > 0)
                    emptySpace.getLayoutParams().width =  emptySpaceWidth;

                MobileIframeWebView.openedIframe.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                MobileIframeWebView.openedIframe.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

                MobileIframeWebView.openedIframe.setWebViewClient(MobileIframeWebView.client);
                MobileIframeWebView.openedIframe.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                if(MobileIframeWebView.javascriptInterface != null)
                    MobileIframeWebView.openedIframe.addJavascriptInterface(MobileIframeWebView.javascriptInterface, MobileIframeWebView.javascriptInterfaceName);

                MobileIframeWebView.openedIframe.loadUrl(MobileIframeWebView.url);

                closewv.setOnTouchListener(new MobileIframeOnTouchListener(MobileIframeWebView.openedIframe));

                MobileIframeWebView.popup.showAtLocation(MobileIframeWebView.activity.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Why not just a regular WebView? Also there's a Facebook & Google SDK for Authentication.

Comment: I am using the Chromium webview (v37) that is loaded dynamically. Isnt that the regular one?

Comment: Could you please link me the facebook and google sdk you use for authentication? In case this doesnt work out, I might try that, Thanks

Comment: Use Google to find them.